# Why does my regex not match space

Tags: regex

Here's my regex:

```
\b((?:Text|Header|Content))\=\"([^{].+?)\"
```

I'm trying to match strings like this:

> Text="My Text" Width="50"

which is working fine - I get:

> Capture group 1: Text Capture group 2: My Text

But when it encounters this text:

> Text=" " Width="50"

I get the following result:

> Capture group 1: Text Capture group 2: " Width=

What am I doing wrong with my regex?

**Edit:** there's an added complication in my regex - I'm excluding matching text line:

Text="{Binding Test}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your regex matches your attribute values (within quotes):

```
([^{].+?)
```

This is interpreted as any character other than `{`, followed by one or more characters. Thus, you regex requires your attribute value to have at least *two* characters, causing it to fail for the single-character space in `Text=" "`.

To fix this issue, you can change your quantifier to match zero or more characters instead:

```
([^{].*?)
```